# Change mark color programmatically

Tags: vega-lite

I want to change the color of bars programatically, i.e. the color.value property that I put in the spec.

I have multiple vega charts that are ordered and I want to represent the order by coloring the bars with the [category10](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/#scheme-reference) set, for example. I.e. the first chart is blue, second orange, thrid green, etc.
If the order changes, the color should get updated (everything else remains the same).

My first approach was to use the SVG renderer and simply re-style the bars:https://codepen.io/keckelt/pen/ExaJwdV :

```js
 d3.select('#vis1').selectAll('svg .mark-rect > path').style('fill', '#A1E');
```

Hovering one of the bars however breaks my applied styling so I need a way to reset the color that Vega is using when the standard color gets applied again. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you set the colors via the scale domain and range as in https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/stacked_bar_weather.html? This way the color mapping stays consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The color scale can be changed by updating the underlying d3 scale's range via the [View API](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#view_scale), e.g.:

```js
//get color scale
const oldColors = vegaView.scale('color').range();

//set new color scale
const newcolor = ['#A1E'];
vegaView.scale('color').range(newColor);
```

The change wasn't reflected by the visualization (even with a `runAysnc()`) so I combined the change of the color scale with changing the SVG element color (as in the original question):

```
 d3.select('#vis1').selectAll('svg .mark-rect > path').style('fill', '#A1E');
```